# RTC - Error during check-in, Files are marked as additions but already exist in the repository

Tags: eclipse-plugin, rtc, rational-team-concert

In Eclipse I am receiving the following error when trying to check-in some local changes.

RTC - 4.0.6 (RTC Client Plugin for Eclipse)

```
Errors encountered during Check-in
Parent '/WLSample/apps/wlapp/ipad/css' has multiple children with the name 'main.css'.
Parent '/WLSample/apps/wlapp/ipad/css' has multiple children with the name 'main.css'.
```

The main/remote repository and my repository workspace already contain these files that are being checked-in. However, the Pending Changes view shows the files as being additions instead of being flagged as edited.

Comment: As of now the only solution I have found is to reload the project.

Comment: Is there a case issue (lower vs uppercase)?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be a case issue, files are both named the same. This file is in fact the same file from the repository that I previously checked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you can try somthing like
1. Revert the latest chages from css file and check that under pending changes there should not be any unresolved or addition files changes.
2. After checking this, again if due to latest changes effect as files addition then revert the line by line and check the status of pending changes.